# how to capitalize the 1st letter of input field text while typing by javasccript?

Tags: javascript

i want to know that when we type the name in input field type text. i want to get the input by user but while typing i want to capitalize the 1st letter that user enter. please help me

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body> 
<form name="inputform">
Name: <input name="name" type="text" id="n" onKeyPress="check()"> 
</form>
<script>
    function check()
{
    var name=document.getElementById("n");
    var uppercase=name.value.charAt(0);

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it gets:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}; //                   ^ First letter + The rest of the string.
```

Use it like this:

```
function check() {
    var name = document.getElementById("n");
    var uppercase = capitalizeFirstLetter(name.value);
    name.value = uppercase;
}
```

Or, shorter:

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="n" onKeyUp="check(this)">
```

```
function check(element) {
    element.value = capitalizeFirstLetter(element.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function in check method

like this

```
function capitalize(s) {
 // returns the first letter capitalized + the string from index 1 and out aka. the rest of the string
return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substr(1);
}

function check()
{
  var name=document.getElementById("n");
  var uppercase = capitalize(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript function toUpperCase().
Here you have the code:

```
document.getElementById("n").addEventListener("keyup",checkinput);
function checkinput(){
    var name=document.getElementById("n");
    if(name.value.length==1){
        var uppercase=name.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        name.value=uppercase;
    }
}
```